# IN() operator with AND inside

Tags: sql

In SQL, IN() operator allow to check if something inside the IN is equal to something OR something OR something etc..

But I want to do the same thing with AND inside the IN() like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1 AND id = 2
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: This would only make sense inside a group where you can use post grouping filtering to check for both conditions.

Comment: How could `id = 1 AND id = 2` be true for any id? Can you give some sample data, and how the transformed IN would help to solve a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an aditional table,

```
TableIN
 1
 2
```

Then perform a `JOIN` with `HAVING`.

```
 SELECT T.*
 FROM Table T
 JOIN TableIN TI
   ON T.id = TI.id
 HAVING count(distinct T.id) = (select count(id) from TableIN)
```